# How to make jQuery button set of regular buttons

Tags: jquery, button, uibutton

I have implemented the jQuery buttonset of radio buttons using this HTML:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="radio" id="1" /><label for="1">Button 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="2" /><label for="2">Button 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="3" /><label for="3">Button 3</label>
</div>
```

Then in Javascript:

```
$('#buttons').buttonset()
```

This works OK. But I do not want the toggle feature.  I just want button functionality.  After you click it I do not want the button to stay highlighted like a toggle button.  The reason I like this button set is the styling, all the buttons are grouped together side by side very nice.  Does anyone know how to make this button set have the same styling but just have basic button functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want radio-button like features *remove the `"radio"` type from your inputs...*

Just use `<button>` tags instead!